# Is it possible to create Azure Databricks Cluster using PowerShell script?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

Is it possible to create Azure Databricks Cluster using Powershell?

Only ARM supported to create Azure Databricks basic level. but I need to do automation to creation of Databricks cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [azure.databricks.cicd.tools module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/azure.databricks.cicd.tools):

`Install-Module -Name azure.databricks.cicd.tools -Scope CurrentUser`

Inside the module there is a command to create cluster:

`New-DatabricksCluster`

More info about the module and command list you can find [here](https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools).